# Click button to switch iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, button, iframe

I have 3 iframes, now I want make 3 buttons when I click on button, it will change iframes

This is my code

```
<button value="iframe 1" target="myiframe"></button>
<button value="iframe 2" target="myiframe"></button>
<button value="iframe 3" target="myiframe"></button>

<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

Is this good? and I wonder if all 3 iframes will load one time?
 I just want when page load load iframe 1 first, not iframe 2 and 3.
If any code better, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<button type="button"  data-src="http://localhost:8080/1">1</button>
<button type="button"  data-src="http://localhost:8080/2">2</button>
<button type="button"  data-src="http://localhost:8080/3">3</button>

<iframe id="iframe" src="http://localhost:8080/1"></iframe>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', $(this).data('src'))
})
</script>
```

*Note: change data-src and src attribute according to your requirement.

Comment: Tks,but it doesn work,not sure what im wrong,i pasted your code on my html page but it not work.

Comment: Include this in your page . <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>